# OpenCV - How to detect marker with alpha channel

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to detect custom forms like crosses.
I tried to use matchTemplate, but the background color of the marker is not always the same.
If I use a alpha channel in a marker png, I don't get a good result.
Maybe I have to set up a ROI?
What is a good way to detect this forms?

Comment: OpenCV ignores alpha channel of images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using another color space where foreground and background are better separated?

- use grayscale version if your markers are typically brighter than background
- convert to HSV space and then only use Saturation and Value, e.g. if you have white markers on colored background

matchTemplate() does not work with a mask ("foreground-only" template).

Comment: I use a monochrome camera. 
I have two types of marker:
- black, if the background is bright
- white, if the background is dark

Comment: Then you should use a template with white/black and it should work fine.